# Use mysql function as column name

Tags: mysql

Column name is dynamic like today it is 14 so where column name is 14 and value is A.Return rows.

But it is not giving any result.

```
SELECT * FROM student_attendance WHERE CONCAT('\'',DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) ,'\'') LIKE '%A%'
```

This will be actually like

```
SELECT * FROM student_attendance WHERE `14` = 'A'
```

Comment: please rephrase the question, your problem was not understood

Comment: Column names are not dynamic in SQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation functions are going to return strings, not references to schema objects.

If you *absolutely must* have a "dynamic" column name then you're probably going to have to dynamically build the query as a string and execute that.  Probably [using `EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html) with a string as a query statement.  Something like:

```
PREPARE query FROM 'SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE ' + CONCAT('\'',DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) ,'\'') + ' LIKE somevalue';
EXECUTE query;
```

It might take a bit of tinkering to get it to work right, I don't have an example in front of me that I can test.

***However***, you're *much better off* defining a more static schema so you can easily query the data.  If your schema is *dynamic* and changes more often than the code itself changes then you're basically using relational databases wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this should be possible but after a few attempts I still couldn't get a query to work.

However, I would advise not using this schema as it is just going to cause problems.

Rather than having a column for every day of the month, it would be better to abstract it to something like the following:

```
id | day | month | year |       created_at    | student_id | status
 1 |  14 |   07  | 2015 | 2015-07-14 09:00:00 |          1 |      A
```

Then you will also get the benefit of adding indices to the `day`, `month`, `year` and `student_id` columns.

Even if you got your current query to work, using functions such as `CONCAT`, `DAYOFMONTH`, `CURRENT_DATE` and `LIKE` means every query you execute involves a full table scan and when your table grows in size, your queries will eventually take a long time to complete, whereas, with the structure above you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM student_attendance
WHERE `day` = 14 AND `month` = 7 AND `year` = 2015 AND `status` = 'A'
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM student_attendance
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2015-07-14 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-14 11:59:59'
AND `status` = 'A'
```

Although, it would be best not to use `day`, `month` and `year` as column names since they are reserved words but they are for example only.

This is also assuming you are running the query via some server side language (to populate the date variables), which might not be the case, if not, you are always going to be using MYSQL functions, which, as mentioned previously, will result in slow queries with large data sets.